# MySQL PHP multiple WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

Here is my SQL code for a search box (table contains rankings for M and F) and I want to get data only for M:

```
"SELECT *
   FROM players WHERE gender = 'M' AND
   name LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
   OR surname LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
 ";
```

I try to get values for players who are Men (M)

So it's important that Gender was M but for second and third WHERE clause I want to put OR

Comment: You do not do the work for others here, but you help people by checking their code for mistakes or by helping people get started. I'll give you a generic example of a MYsqli to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want something like this?

```
"SELECT *
   FROM players WHERE gender = 'M' AND
   ( name LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
   OR surname LIKE '%{$keywords}%')
 ";
```